# how to replace link text with image

Tags: jquery

How might I replace a link text with an image?

I tried this script already:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a:contains("edit")').html('<img src="edit.png"/>');
});
```

but did not have any luck.
Am I doing something wrong here?

html

```
<a href="/ideas/bpul_dishes/edit">Edit</a>
```

Comment: Can you create a simple JSFiddle? (http://jsfiddle.net/) That code looks like it should work, so a simple test case whould be nice to see why it doesn't.

Comment: Post your HTML here please.

Comment: Simple test case works: http://jsfiddle.net/t98d7/

Comment: i dont know how to embed an image in jsfiddle.net and I dont have a url for the image

Comment: `:contains` is case sensitive.  The string "Edit" does not contain "edit".

Comment: @JamesMontagne post that as an answer, I bet that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you want. The "edit" needs to be in the href, and not in the text contained in the `a`-tag, right?

http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/t98d7/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href*="edit"]').html('<img src="edit.png"/>');
});
```

If you do mean, as the comments suggest, that the *edit* has to occur within the `a`-tag, then following solution will work. I allowed for starting with a capital letter, if that's necessary.

http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/t98d7/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a:contains("Edit"), a:contains("edit")').html('<img src="edit.png"/>');
});
```

Or with a regular expression (`i` is a modifier, causing the regex to be case insensitive).

http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/t98d7/25/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").filter(function () {
        return /edit/i.test($(this).text());
    }).html('<img src="edit.png"/>');
});
```

Comment: No, not right. He posted his HTML and the "Edit" is in the link's text.

Comment: @j08691 *And* it is in the href. So who knows what he means? But I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Works well and it is just im looking for! Thanks @BramVanroy